# Predicate Logic Maximum

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

If P(x,y) : the pixel on row x and column y is lit. How would I then express that:

> 1. Maximum one pixel is lit on every row
> 2. There is at least one row where exactly 1 pixel is lit.

I have tried using negation without effect. Do you have any tips to help me along the way?

It needs to be expressed as a closed predicate formula

Comment: 1. Would VxVy(P(x,y) -> x =y work?

Comment: 2. Would ExP(x,y)^VxVy(P(x,y)->x=y work?

Answer (score 2):

1. In any row, there is a column and if any column in that row has a lit pixel, then that is it.
2. There is a row where there is a column where the pixel is lit, and no other column in that row has a lit pixel.

Say it with <s>flowers</s> symbols.